# How to update NPM package installed from a Git repository?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I cannot figure out how to update a package installed from a git repository.

Say I have a package at `git+ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:project/my-package.git` and it's already installed.

Now, if I:

1. push into my-package master branch;
2. run npm i or npm update;

then **nothing gets updated**.

I thought the `version` field (from the dependent `package.json` of my-package) might raise the problem so I removed it and re-installed the package from scratch. Unfortunately it didn't help, the package is still not being updated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm git repository not updating versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367250/npm-git-repository-not-updating-versions)

Comment: @RobC Thanks, I saw that topic but it doesn't answer my question. The author uses commit hash which is not my case as I need my package to follow just the latest changes which is master branch I guess.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the node_modules directory, then running `npm i` ?

Comment: Yes, Rob. It fetches the latest version as it should, but right after that it looses the ability to update it further: new commits of the master never get fetched again.

Comment: See issue [#1727](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727#issuecomment-22673783) - I think the only way currently is to re-install it again after each each commit to git. However, I'm sure this will be a feature [very soon](https://github.blog/2020-03-16-npm-is-joining-github/) !

Comment: Yeah, who would even guess. I thought I was missing something, like version field, or maybe #branch postfix. But it has never been working! LOL. Ok, I'm gonna answer myself, explaining how I finally worked it around (which is just a copy-paste from the last comment of the thread you linked). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, folks. Suprisingly, it doesn't seem possible to get it working out-of-the-box.

But there is a workaround. Thanks to @RobC for pointing me out to some old (yet never resolved) issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727

The answer is in the last comment:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727#issuecomment-354124625

Basically, to **update** a git package you have to **re-install** it directly using: `npm install package-name`.

Example. Say you already have your package installed and added to the dependencies like this:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "my-package": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.my.com:prj/my-package.git"
    }
}
```

Now, to get it updated whenever you issue `npm i`  all you have to do is to create a `postinstall` script which would trigger `npm i my-package`:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "my-package": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.my.com:prj/my-package.git"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "npm update && npm i my-package"
    }
}
```

Now `npm i` will be taking more time since it's gonna run install twice. But this is what we have now.